# Xamarin fill gridview

Tags: sql, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin , i want to fill my gridview by value , 
but i don't know what to write in while methode

```
 var gridview1 = FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.gvd);
 var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=45.219.173.49;Initial Catalog=DB_B2B;user=test; Password=test");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from en_cours ");
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    SqlDataReader sqlreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (sqlreader.Read())
                    {
                    //your answer here 

                    }
                    sqlreader.Close();
                    con.Close();
```

this is my grid

```
<GridView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/gvd" />
```

Comment: You question is way too broad to be answered in a single question. Essentially you need to populate some kind of model from your SQL query, then present that in a grid. There are a lot of ways to do this. It would be much better if you spent time looking at the vast samples that Xamarin provides, for instance the Todo App: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/todo/ then retrofit that to show some of your data and work your way to populate a GridView.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the below documentation to learn about how to work with Xamarin.Android GridView.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/grid-view

The below article will give you more details about working with GridView and adapters.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/grid-view-with-multiple-rows-and-two-columns-xamarinandroid

You can also refer the below links for a better understanding.

- https://camposha.info/xamarin-android-custom-gridview-with-images-and-textbaseadapter/
- https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/